# Linear Regression Bad Performance Metrics

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying out linear regression on a data set of 637 observations and 10 features. it looks like this. 100 rows

**train_X:**

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.33178298,  0.26865475,  0.        , -0.72870151,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -1.59016455, -1.05162249,  0.        , -0.88503151,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -0.50119857, -1.42884455,  0.        , -1.04136151,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  2.0321526 ,  0.77161751,  0.        , -0.74172901,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.80988656,  1.21170993,  0.        , -0.70264651,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.76509649, -0.61153007,  0.        ,  1.40780853,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.45653173,  1.71467268,  1.        , -1.11952651,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  2.70376764,  1.58893199,  0.        , -0.5202615 ,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.384769  ,  1.71467268,  1.        ,  0.76946102,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.63022298, -1.4917149 ,  1.        , -0.272739  ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.90568353,  0.64587682,  0.        , -0.97622401,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.20929581, -0.234308  ,  1.        , -1.08044401,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -0.73550689, -0.48578938,  0.        , -0.74172901,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.94401033, -0.61153007,  1.        , -1.01530651,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.53615764, -0.42291904,  1.        ,  0.53496601,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.28134099, -0.67440042,  1.        , -0.87200401,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.53113224, -0.48578938,  1.        ,  1.68138603,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.34416932, -0.61153007,  0.        ,  1.52505603,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -1.27362468, -1.68032593,  1.        ,  1.18634102,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.10951694, -0.234308  ,  0.        ,  1.87679853,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.28966016,  0.45726579,  1.        , -0.5463165 ,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -1.67618082, -1.4917149 ,  1.        , -0.91108651,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.025221  , -0.54865973,  1.        ,  0.13111351,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.04001579, -0.61153007,  1.        , -0.72870151,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.99424383, -0.80014111,  0.        , -0.481179  ,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70337327,  0.8973582 ,  0.        , -1.06741651,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -1.39404746, -1.11449283,  0.        ,  1.65533103,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.86418723, -0.42291904,  1.        , -1.06741651,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -1.69751285, -1.24023352,  1.        ,  0.73037852,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.17949773, -0.73727076,  0.        , -0.5202615 ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.1571335 , -0.54865973,  0.        , -0.97622401,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.42378393, -0.86301145,  1.        , -0.168519  ,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.4074773 ,  1.65180234,  1.        ,  1.10817602,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.37135047, -0.80014111,  0.        , -0.66356401,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.74795485,  0.64587682,  0.        , -0.012189  ,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.82020851,  1.02309889,  0.        , -0.376959  ,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -0.97015928, -1.4917149 ,  0.        , -0.97622401,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.55390214,  1.40032096,  1.        , -0.0773265 ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.38132835, -0.10856731,  1.        , -0.74172901,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -0.68974624, -0.17143766,  1.        , -0.75475651,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  2.27093377,  1.33745062,  1.        ,  0.96487352,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -1.43533526, -1.05162249,  0.        , -0.78081151,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -1.85647092, -1.61745559,  0.        ,  0.53496601,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.48867666,  1.58893199,  1.        , -0.376959  ,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.31643563,  0.39439544,  1.        , -0.96319651,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.02350067,  0.8973582 ,  1.        ,  0.99092852,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.10724406,  0.8973582 ,  0.        ,  0.95184602,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -1.59016455, -0.73727076,  1.        ,  0.33955351,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.09437808,  0.58300648,  1.        , -0.5463165 ,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  2.3720889 ,  1.52606165,  0.        , -1.09347151,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.66875827, -0.234308  ,  0.        , -0.1554915 ,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.72828153, -0.29717835,  1.        , -0.84594901,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  2.67073739,  1.33745062,  0.        ,  0.83459852,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.36185222, -0.10856731,  0.        , -0.012189  ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  2.10303001,  0.96022855,  0.        ,  1.70744103,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.05219365, -0.10856731,  1.        , -0.89805901,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.90203439, -0.73727076,  1.        ,  1.19936852,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.62492643,  0.45726579,  1.        ,  1.82468853,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -0.77266592, -0.48578938,  1.        , -0.5463165 ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.21183984, -0.54865973,  1.        , -0.5463165 ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.55164057,  0.83448786,  0.        ,  1.98101854,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.1217564 ,  0.8973582 ,  0.        ,  0.33955351,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -1.10640905, -1.11449283,  1.        , -1.02833401,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -1.22201492, -1.36597421,  0.        , -0.533289  ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.38180799, -1.4917149 ,  1.        , -0.5984265 ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.26778688,  0.08004372,  1.        ,  1.94193604,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.14337089,  0.20578441,  1.        , -0.4160415 ,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  2.46154582,  1.27458027,  0.        ,  0.41771851,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -1.30321427, -1.55458524,  1.        , -1.11952651,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -0.78161161, -0.73727076,  0.        , -0.70264651,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.58762052,  0.70874717,  0.        , -0.298794  ,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -1.00181326, -0.86301145,  1.        , -0.83292151,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.38800116, -0.98875214,  1.        , -1.13255401,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.77872352,  1.21170993,  0.        , -0.93714151,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -1.28807541, -0.36004869,  1.        ,  1.92890854,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -0.50704768, -0.17143766,  0.        , -0.116409  ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.42949746,  1.14883958,  0.        ,  0.82157102,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.46940901, -0.61153007,  1.        , -0.96319651,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.29187143,  0.52013613,  0.        , -1.04136151,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.92136365,  1.21170993,  0.        , -0.68961901,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -1.33624452, -1.24023352,  0.        , -0.87200401,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -0.45474979, -0.73727076,  0.        ,  1.87679853,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.46803275,  1.65180234,  1.        , -1.02833401,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.39337063,  0.20578441,  0.        ,  1.53808353,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.49555796,  1.08596924,  1.        ,  1.14725852,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.42860084, -0.9258818 ,  0.        , -0.74172901,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.34416932,  0.01717338,  0.        , -1.04136151,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -0.5817098 , -1.42884455,  1.        ,  0.50891101,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -1.40161689, -1.4917149 ,  0.        ,  0.09203101,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.34210493, -0.48578938,  0.        ,  2.09826604,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.34946587,  0.26865475,  0.        ,  2.09826604,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.93527313,  0.3315251 ,  1.        , -1.09347151,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.49074105, -0.48578938,  0.        , -0.87200401,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.70454104, -0.98875214,  1.        ,  0.31349851,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.95542609,  1.58893199,  0.        , -0.5463165 ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.56161845, -0.36004869,  1.        ,  1.59019353,
         1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.93871378, -0.10856731,  1.        , -0.97622401,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.10208308,  0.3315251 ,  0.        , -0.83292151,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.56140996, -1.36597421,  0.        ,  0.88670852,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.34416932, -0.61153007,  0.        ,  0.11808601,
         0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])
```

Similarly 100 corresponding Y variable which is a count of transactions looks like this

**train_Y:**

```
array([ 3, 11,  3,  4,  6, 11,  9,  2, 13,  4,  1, 10, 13,  8,  5,  8,  1,
       11,  1, 10,  6,  3,  8,  3,  8,  2, 20,  9, 13,  9,  3,  4,  8,  2,
        1,  3,  5,  6,  3,  1,  3,  9,  2, 14,  4,  9,  4, 13, 10,  2, 15,
        1,  2,  8,  4, 12, 14,  3, 13,  3, 11,  7, 10, 10,  6, 13,  5,  5,
       10,  9,  2,  4,  5,  3, 19,  5,  4,  2,  7,  5,  6,  1,  9,  1,  1,
        1, 12,  5, 11,  3,  5, 12,  2,  3,  3,  4,  3,  5,  2,  4])
```

Now I am running few Linear regression algos like this using Grid Search for HP tuning.

```
class TotalReservations(object):
    """ Class to carry out machine learning tasks """



    def __init__(self,train_X_std,train_Y,test_X_std,test_Y,estimator,param_grid):
        """ Constructor to initialze the data

        """

        self.train_X=train_X_std
        self.train_Y=train_Y
        self.test_X=test_X_std
        self.test_Y=test_Y
        # The hyper parameter grid for this estimator
        self.param_grid=param_grid
        # The actual ML estimator from sklearn
        self.estimator=estimator



    def grid_search(self):

            """This function does Cross Validation using Grid Search

            """

            from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
            self.g_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=self.estimator,param_grid=self.param_grid,cv=5)
            self.g_cv.fit(self.train_X,self.train_Y)



        def train_performance(self):
            """ Method to get the training performance of the estimator across all parameters

            """

            self.mean_train_score=self.g_cv.cv_results_['mean_train_score']
            self.mean_val_score=self.g_cv.cv_results_['mean_test_score']

            # Printing the Dummy Regressor score
            self.dummy_regressor(self.train_X,self.train_Y,self.test_X,self.test_Y)

            print("\nThe mean train scores are {}\n".format(self.mean_train_score))

            print("The mean validation scores are {}\n".format(self.mean_val_score))

            print("The score on held out data is: {score}\n Hyper-Parameters for Best Score : {param}\n"\
            .format(score=self.g_cv.best_score_,param=self.g_cv.best_params_))
```

I run first ridge regression with following parameter grid values.

```
# For Ridge Regression
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
ridge_lr=Ridge(random_state=42)

#***************************************************************************************


    # Creating Hyperparameter values Grid for Random Forests
    # Actual to be used 


    # Creating Hyperparameters values Grid for Ridge Regression
    grid_ridge={'alpha':[0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1.0]}
```

This gives me very poor R2 values and MSE. Note I have done 5 Fold Cross Validation that is why we have 5 sets of values for training and validation scores for each fold and the mean scores across all 5.

The score here in Sklearn by default I think is R2 score.

```
td_ridge.grid_search()

# Training Performance of SGD Regressor
td_ridge.train_performance()


The mean train scores are [0.21945918 0.21945918 0.21945917 0.2194588  0.21942437]

The mean validation scores are [0.18215611 0.18215637 0.18215894 0.18218431 0.18240627]

The score on held out data is: 0.18240626691460574
 Hyper-Parameters for Best Score : {'alpha': 1.0}

The R2 Score of ridge_regressor on test data is: 0.17520249693363288

The mse of ridge_regressor on test data is: 17.791933297637534
The mean absolute error of ridge_regressor on test data is: 3.381908224949849
```

I tried Random forest Regressor too but same results.

Any idea what is going on here? Why are the scores so bad?

Comment: Making 10 scatterplots, one for each feature variable vs. Y, could be informative, and might suggest some obvious data transform such as log that might help the regression. This should be quick to perform, and because this is fast it is worth trying.

Comment: You should also normalize your data set.

Comment: Since best alpha is 1.0, try again GridSearch with alpha = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000], 100 data points is very small, you might overfit the model

Comment: I just put 100 here. In reality I have around 600+ training and 237 testing. I do cross validation on 600 training data points.

Comment: @TimH not sure I understand. My continuous variable (3 of them) are standardized (z score). Rest are binary. I don't think u need to normalize the rows. That makes sense if u r dealing with text features (tf-idf) etc.

Comment: I've tried to run Ridge and Linear regressions on the data you provided and there is a flat minimum of the r^2 score for values of alpha around 300,000. Also, the coefficient of determination you are looking at can be negative and returns 0 when you output the mean of your outputs. Moreover, most of your binary values have similar distribution within the groups formed by the output values (0 and 1). This can be a coincidence but the 9-th row has only values values equal to .

Comment: Am trying to understand why is this not working? I mean its a basic level data. And there shud be a relationship between the target and features. It gives pathetic R2. Am I doing something wrong in calling the right methods?